# How do we know the actual position of the Andromeda galaxy, if we are seeing 2.5 million years in the past?

Tags: universe, collision, galaxies

Scientists estimate that [Andromeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) and The Milky Way are going to [collide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision) in about 2.5 million years, how accurate is that calculation?

Comment: The scientists probably are acting under the _assumption_ that neither galaxy is going perform any sudden, evasive manouvers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relative velocity between the Milky Way and Andromeda is of order 100 km/s. In 2.5 million years this amounts to relative motion of around 800 light years.

Since the size of both galaxies is of order 100,000 light years, and their current separation is *about* 2.5 million light years, any uncertainty in the position due to finite light travel time is quite negligible compared with the uncertainties in sizes and separation.