# Can we see galaxies that tell us what the Milky Way will be like in future time?

Tags: spacetime, universe, galaxies

When we are looking at any galaxy we look usually at past time. As in case of Andromeda Galaxy we are looking at 2.5 million years back.

In the same way do we have galaxy which will show future galaxy. Because milky way is not start of the galaxy. There might be the galaxy which will show us future galaxy. As currently all galaxy are showing few million years past.

Are there any galaxies that appear similar to ours but older, giving us a view of what the Milky Way will look like in the future?

Comment: Why do you think it is the case that we see the past of a galaxy?

Comment: @KyleKanos https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351096/

Comment: @KyleKanos And in many videos on youtube they always mention it took n million years to travel light from that galaxy to earth. (n denoting number)

Comment: That's better: "it took *n* million years to travel light" In that case, what would have to happen for us to see a galaxy *as it will be in the future*

Comment: @KyleKanos The view what we r looking at is showing past of that galaxy formation. Is there any galaxy which will show what will be the shape of galaxy later.

Comment: Are you asking if there are any galaxies like ours that are older and thus more advanced, or are you asking whether light can travel back in time from a "later" galaxy to us?

Comment: @Asher I'm asking are there any galaxies like outs that are older than ours and more advanced

Comment: @Asher I know light cant travel back

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad I've edited the question to clarify your intent. If I've got it wrong, please roll back the edit.

Comment: @Asher Thank you for putting my question in proper words.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible because a photon has to traverse a distance to reach us. In order for us to see a galaxy as it would be in the future, the photon would have to reach us (long) *before* the galaxy emits it, which is an impossibility & hence, nonsense.

However, given what we know about [galactic dynamics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8697.html), it is possible to use the information obtained from an observation of a galaxy and model it (e.g., using any number of codes like [Gadget](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/), [ramses](http://www.ics.uzh.ch/~teyssier/ramses/RAMSES.html), etc) to *predict* what the galaxy would look like at some future time (at least to some degree).

Comment: https://amazing-space.stsci.edu/news/archive/2004/03/graphics/cosmic_core_gfk.jpg.  Show us galaxies in past.

Comment: Oh, then you're asking an entirely different question than what you've written. You want to ask if there are galaxies that are *older* than ours, not 'can we see a future galaxy'.

Comment: We are starting point in that image. I just want to know if we can see older and advance galaxy

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to ask

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad then have even bothered to search online if there are older galaxies than ours?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify it, which makes the first portion of your answer irrelevant. The second half is the correct answer to the edited question. I don't know if you may wish to wait and see if the asker keeps the edit before editing your answer.